# How to enable screen orientation only on certain devices (e.g. iPads/tablets)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making a simple game with Expo. In `app.json` there's a possibility of setting screen orientation by setting the `"orientation": "portrait"`.

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "orientation": "portrait",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

That is great, but when on iPad (or tablets in general) the game is much nicer in the landscape. Is there any way of **unlocking** screen orientation **only** on tablets?

Comment: Apps which lock the orientation mostly do it because the app doesn't handle orientation changes properly. If you app works fine in both potrait and landscape, why lock it? Let people use the app in whichever orientation they want.

Comment: Because it is better for the type of the game to be locked on small screens (phones), but to let it be switched on tablets.

Comment: I play most games in landscape on my phone so I don't really see why it'd be better to lock it instead of giving a choice. Regardless, it's problematic to lock the orientation on iPad, because the orientation changes during multi-tasking and cause issues. But if you really want to do it, only way to do it is programmatically https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationlockasyncorientationlock

Comment: I should have maybe explained better. I want to lock the orientation on every device BUT the iPad. I saw the link you gave, but it doesn't really help if I want to lock on just one type of devices (tablets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that you can check if the device is an iPad simply by using `Platform` from `react-native`. The complete solution is below:

`expo-screen-orientation` needs to be installed

```shell
expo install expo-screen-orientation
```

and imported like this:

```js
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';
```

Also, `Platform` should be imported from `react-native`

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```

After that, it's simply a matter of checking if the device is an iPad and if so unlock the orientation.

```js
if (Platform.isPad) {
    await ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync();
}
```

Note that changes will not be shown in the Expo app because that app has default orientation and it can't be locked (at least not on iOS).

Of course, in `app.json` the orientation should be set to `'portrait'`

```
  "expo": {
   ...
    "orientation": "portrait",
   ...
  }
```

Update: Tested on Expo `36.0.0` and `ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync()` **is not supported**. Worked after upgrading to `38.0.0`. Tested on `39.0.0.`, `40.0.0` and it works fine as well.

## Additional Setup For Bare Workflows

For bare workflows additional setup is required.
Follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-screen-orientation) from expo. Try building the app. If it fails make sure the import they stated is the second line just after `#import "AppDelegate.h"`

You should use the first option from their tutorial:

```c
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[EXScreenOrientationViewController alloc] init]; // The default screen orientation will be set to `portrait`.
```

Which will set the default orientation to portrait.
After that, you'll need to open your project in XCode and check that the app supports all four rotations
[image: Support all four rotations in app]

After that everything should work: App orientation is locked to portrait unless the person is on an iPad

Comment: Using `Device.getDeviceTypeAsync()` from `expo-device` allows this to work for Android tablets as well